# Error when using property assigned in parent constructor

Tags: php

When I call a method on a property instantiated in a parent class' constructor as follows:

```
class A
{
    function AA()
    {

    }
}

class C
{
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->A = new A();
    }
}

class B extends C
{
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->A->AA();
    }
}
```

I get this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function AA() on a non-object in…

Why is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because constructors don't call parent constructors by default. You can trigger it with `parent::__construct()`.